# RAID level 1 of 2 Network Block Devices

Tags: linux, rsync, software-raid, mdadm

I currently have a RAID level 1 of 2 500 GB HDs. The RAID is managed by server 1 and the drives are in 2 different servers.

The RAID works great once I get it setup, however, at random times the connection seems to get dropped and mdadm marks it as faulty and even though I use nbd-client with the -persist option; mdadm refuses to see the drive as good. The only way to get this disconnect drive back into the RAID array is to:
mdadm -r /dev/md0 /dev/nbd1
mdadm -a /dev/md0 /dev/nbd1

My problem with this is that it causes a FULL RESYNC of 500GB over the network.
I have 2 questions to this problem:
Is there a way to tell mdadm not to complete a full resync because it does complete a resync before it disconnects so I can't see a good reason for it to perform a FULL resync?
Would I be better off with rsync because all I need is just a backup copy of whatever data I write/delete? I suggest this because rsync, supposedly, only transfers the delta (or changed) data instead of what mdadm seems to be doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wow, I haven't heard of anyone using NBD in a while.

Have you considered using [DRBD](http://www.drbd.org/) instead?

It's [features](http://www.drbd.org/home/feature-list/) include automatic recovery from network failures and differential resynchronisation.

---

Better yet, it's [going mainline](http://www.linux-magazine.com/Online/News/DRBD-Merged-into-Mainline-Kernel)!

Comment: DRBD is awesome.

Comment: +1 for DRBD is awesome

Answer (score 2):

Seconding the suggestion to use DRBD, because this is exactly the scenario for which it was designed.  You also get the ability to mask local disk errors -- if the local disk fails, DRBD can serve blocks from the remote disk so that as far as the OS knows it still has a fully functional disk.

DRBD also has the necessary infrastructure to manage failover and consistency in ways that are superior to using a simple software RAID solution.

Answer (score 2):

Whilst I would never in my right mind consider doing network RAID 1 over NBD, and am a massive fan of DRBD for all things "HA storage", there is one point in your question that is applicable to other mdadm situations.  You said:

> Is there a way to tell mdadm not to complete a full resync

Yes, there is.  Check `mdadm`(8) for "write-intent bitmap" -- basically, it's a way for mdadm to remember which blocks are in sync, and only resync those that it doesn't know are up to date.  In your situation I'd still use DRBD, but for large local RAID sets, it can help a lot after a crash, too.

Comment: +1 good tip.  i didn't know mdadm had this capability.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to suggest something other than DRBD.. and that's [GlusterFS](http://www.gluster.com/).  It's got a whole bunch of different storage mechansims, you can simulate RAID across multiple block devices, by striping across them, or mirroring, or having a RAID-5 like array structure.

You can also do cool stuff like encryption.  The only downside is it's FUSE based, but in recent RHEL/CentOS kernels this is fine.  It's fine on Ubuntu/Debian also.

(I don't work for gluster, but I do use it on some large-scale installations, and it's a damn good network filesystem.)

Answer (score -2):

Yep, RAID is the wrong technology to use in this scenario.  You want to either go with rsync or look at some of the distributed file systems that are being developed.

Comment: rsync is the wrong technology for this scenario, too.

Comment: You can't say that rsync is wrong too, because the OP has not said anything about what they are doing at a higher level.  Something like DRBD might be complete overkill.  On the other hand it is never a good idea to use RAID like this.